# CircleCI migration: Config file

Tags: circleci-2.0

I need to migrate from CirlceCI 1.0 to 2.0
I am trying to follow the steps mentioned in their documentation. But unable to get the correct config file.
My Version 1.0 file looks like:

```
    ## Customize the test machine
    machine:

      timezone:
        America/New_York # List of timezones http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

      # Version of ruby to use
      ruby:
        version:
          2.3.1

    ## Customize database setup
    database:
      override:
        # replace Circle's generated database.yml
        - cp config/database.yml.ci config/database.yml
        - bundle exec rake db:create db:schema:load --trace

    test:
      minitest_globs:
        - test/**/*_test.rb

    steps:
      - checkout
        - post:
          - mkdir -p tmp
```

To migrate to Version 2, the modifications made are:

```
    version: 2
    ## Customize the test machine
    jobs:
      build:
        timezone:
          America/New_York # List of timezones http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

        # Version of ruby to use
        docker:
          - image: circleci/ruby:2.3-jessie

      ## Customize database setup
      database:
        - override:
          # replace Circle's generated database.yml
          - cp config/database.yml.ci config/database.yml
          - bundle exec rake db:create db:schema:load --trace

      test:
        - minitest_globs:
          - test/**/*_test.rb

      steps:
        - checkout:
        - run: mkdir -p tmp
```

On executing the CLI command for verification as follows:
circleci config validate -c .circleci/config.yml
I get the error:
         Error: 3 errors occurred:

```
     * Error migrating config to version 2: 2 errors occurred:

     * in job 'build': steps is not a list
     * in job 'build': steps is not a list
     * Config file is invalid:
      at jobs: steps: steps is required
      at jobs: timezone: Additional property timezone is not allowed
      at jobs: jobs: Invalid type. Expected: object, given: array
      at jobs: jobs: Invalid type. Expected: object, given: array
      at jobs: jobs: Invalid type. Expected: object, given: array

     * Error in config file: The schema/shape of the YAML is incorrect: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type config.JobDescription
```

Request you to help me understand where I am going wrong and the modifications needed.

Thanks,
M

Comment: Did you end up resolving your issue?  I got the same error and my yaml file was validated through https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator/ beforehand.  So it's a bit strange that circle ci doesn't like it.

Comment: No, I finally had to remove CircleCI (temporarily due to time constraint).

Answer (score 1):

CircleCI 2.0 deprecates some options you are using, and requires others.

1. [timezone is set as an environment variable](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/faq/#how-can-i-set-the-timezone-in-docker-images)
2. [Databases are declared as additional docker images](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/postgres-config/#example-circleci-configuration-for-a-rails-app-with-structuresql)
3. All activities occur as `steps` inside the `job`

f

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    # Version of ruby to use
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.3-jessie      
        environment:
          TZ: "/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles"
      - image: circleci/postgres:9.6.2-alpine            
        environment:
          TZ: "/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles"       
          POSTGRES_USER: root
          POSTGRES_DB: circle-test_test
    steps:  # run inside primary (ruby) container, with access to secondary (DB) container as localhost:db-port
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Database Migration/Setup
          command: bundle exec rake db:create db:schema:load --trace
      - run:
          name: Execute Tests
          command: rspec test/**/*_test.rb  # change to appropriate testing commands
```